C++, Error al guardar archivo.dat
soy nueva en el mundo de la programación, me encuentro trabajando con C++, intento realizar un software de turnos médicos, como proyecto para una materia. Mi problema surgió al momento de guardar los objetos creados dentro de un archivo. Es la primera vez que trabajo con tipo de dato "vector", por ende no sé si esta bien hecha la implementación en la siguiente función:
bool TurnosArchivo::guardar(const vector<Turnos>& turnos) {
     FILE* p = fopen("turnos.dat", "ab");
    if (p == nullptr) {
        std::cerr << "Error al abrir el archivo turnos.dat para guardar." << std::endl;
        return false;
    }
    bool result = fwrite(turnos.data(), sizeof(Turnos), turnos.size(), p) == turnos.size();
    fclose(p);
    if (!result) {
        std::cerr << "Error al escribir en el archivo turnos.dat." << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cerr << "Turnos guardados correctamente. Cantidad: " << turnos.size() << std::endl;
    }
    return result;
}  

El programa corre, pero al momento de mostrar lo guardado dentro de "turnos.dat" se rompe
void TurnosArchivo::mostrarTurnosPosteriores(const vector<Turnos>& turnos, int matricula, int diaActual, int mesActual, int anioActual, int horaActual, int minutoActual) {
FILE* p = fopen("turnos.dat", "rb");
    if (p == nullptr) {
        std::cout << "No se pudo abrir el archivo." << std::endl;
        return;
    }
    Turnos turno;
    while (fread(&turno, sizeof(Turnos), 1, p)) {
        if (turno.getProfesionalID() == matricula && !turno.getReservado()) {
            Fecha fechaTurno = turno.getFecha();
            string horaTurno = turno.getHora();
            int diaTurno = fechaTurno.getDia();
            int mesTurno = fechaTurno.getMes();
            int anioTurno = fechaTurno.getAnio();
            int hora, minuto;
            sscanf(horaTurno.c_str(), "%d:%d", &hora, &minuto);

            if (anioTurno > anioActual ||
                (anioTurno == anioActual && mesTurno > mesActual) ||
                (anioTurno == anioActual && mesTurno == mesActual &&
                (diaTurno > diaActual || (diaTurno == diaActual &&
                (hora > horaActual || (hora == horaActual && minuto >= minutoActual)))))) {
                cout << "ID: " << turno.getIdTurno() << " - " << fechaTurno.toString() << " " << horaTurno << endl;
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(p);

}

Implemente mensajes de depuración, pero no logro detectar el problema. Quisiera saber si estoy guardando de manera correcta los objetos dentro del archivo.

Deberías mostrar la estructura Turno y Fecha para que podamos reproducir el problema. Viendo que obtienes datos que no son primitivos desde getFecha() y getHora() asumo que tu estructura también tiene esos campos. Por lo tanto, creo que encontrarás la respuesta en esta pregunta.

Spoiler: guardar una estructura entera funciona bien cuando no tiene punteros. Las clases como string pueden contener punteros y solo son válidos durante la ejecución.

El problema está en que escribes el objeto Turnos en disco como si todo el objeto fuese un objeto binario, pero dicho objeto no tiene una representación binaria per se.
fwrite(turnos.data(), sizeof(Turnos), turnos.size(), p)

Puedo ver en el código que compartes que el objeto Turnos tiene sub-objetos complejos, como un miembro del tipo Fecha y otro del tipo std::string. Del tipo Fecha no puedo sacar conclusiones con el código que compartes, pero del tipo std::string puedo decirte que sus datos no los almacena en el propio objeto si no en otra ubicación de memoria:

Los objetos del tipo std::string guardan un puntero a una posición de memoria donde se guarda el texto, si vuelcas en archivo (binariamente) un objeto que contiene un std::string, probablemente acabes guardando el estado binario de ese objeto en un momento de su existencia, esa información ya no es válida cuando vuelcas de archivo a memoria y por eso "se rompe"1.
Si quieres serializar y deserializar datos tienes que tener en cuenta eso; si además estás usando c++ deberás usar los flujos de datos a archivo (fstream) en lugar de FILE de c.
En C++ la manera de serializar objetos es sobrecargando su operador de inyección a flujo de datos:
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using Fecha = int;

struct Turno
{
    // Operador para inyectar datos en flujo de salida (Output Stream)
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &, const Turno &);
    // Operador extraer datos de flujo de entrada(Input Stream)
    friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &, Turno &);

    Fecha fecha;
    std::string Hora;
    int Dia;
    int Mes;
    int Anio;
};

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &o, const Turno &t)
{
    return o << t.fecha << '\n'
             << t.Hora << '\n'
             << t.Dia << '\n'
             << t.Mes << '\n'
             << t.Anio;
}

std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &i, Turno &t)
{
    i >> t.fecha;
    i >> t.Hora;
    i >> t.Dia;
    i >> t.Mes;
    i >> t.Anio;

    return i;
}

Con esos operadores, puedes serializar y deserializar así:
int main()
{
    Turno t{20240717, "23:59:59", 17, 7, 20204};

    // Flujo de salida a archivo (Output File Stream)
    if (std::ofstream datos{"datos.txt"})
        datos << t << '\n'; // <--- Serializar!!

    // Flujo de entrada desde archivo (Input File Stream)
    if (std::ifstream datos{"datos.txt"})
    {
        Turno miturno;
        datos >> miturno; // <--- Deserializar!!

        std::cout << "He leido de archivo:\n\n" << miturno;
    }
}

Con la ventaja añadida que puedes mostrar la misma información por consola. Fíjate que he simplificado tu código al usar Turno sin constructor y al haber hecho que Fecha sea un alias de int, para que este ejemplo funcione debes adaptarlo a tu código añadiendo los mismos operadores a la clase Fecha.
Puedes ver el código funcionando en Compiler explorer.

1Esto es una sobresimplificación del problema, que tiene más matices y consecuencias.
